# Not sure why code returning an Illegal exception related with input data on java 8

Tags: io, java-io, type-constraints, java.lang.class

I have written the code below.

I made a database, with type "Integer" to accept number values, string to accept "Letter" values and "Date" to accept Date values.

Once i run it, i get the above captioned error on the JOptionPane dialog box, and after i click exit on "ok" on the Dialog box, and exit on the JFrame window, it returns  "Build Successful" on the output Window.

Here is the code:

```
private void jBtnSaveMemberActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try{
            
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/merinet","root","philo");
        
        String sql = "insert into Membership values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        
        pstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(jTxtMemberNumber.getText()));
        pstmt.setString(2, jTxtNewMemberLastName.getText());
        pstmt.setString(3, jTxtNewMemberMiddleName.getText());
        pstmt.setString(4, jTxtNewMemberFirstName.getText());
        pstmt.setDate(5, Date.valueOf(jDateChooserMemberDOB.getDateFormatString()));
        pstmt.setInt (6, Integer.parseInt(jTxtNewMemberIdNumber.getText()));
        pstmt.setString(7, jComboBoxMemberGender.getItemAt(1));
        pstmt.setDate(8, Date.valueOf(jDateChooserMemberDofMembership.getDateFormatString()));
        pstmt.setInt(9, Integer.parseInt(jTxtNewMemberPostalAddress.getText()));
        pstmt.setString(10, jComboBoxNewMemberCity.getItemAt(1));
        pstmt.setString(11, jComboBoxNewMemberCounty.getItemAt(1));
        pstmt.setString(12, jComboBoxNewMemberCitizenship.getItemAt(1));
        pstmt.setString(13, jComboBoxNewMemberCountry.getItemAt(1));
        pstmt.setString(14, jTxtNewMemberEmail.getText());
        pstmt.setString(15, jTxtNewMemberCellPhone1.getText());
        pstmt.setString(16, jTxtNewMemberCellPhoneNumber2.getText());
                
            conn.close();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        
    }
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? I also suggest you add  `e.printStackTrace()` to the catch-block to get a full stack trace. That's usually much more useful than just the error message alone.

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: for input string'''     Is the error being returned on the dialog box

Comment: And the stack trace? In short: one of your values can't be parsed into a number because it's an empty string.